# Append to same file from different processes concurrently on MacOS

Tags: node.js, macos, concurrency, append

Is it possible to concurrently append to one file data from different Node.js services on macOS or are there limitations imposed by filesystem/OS?

Comment: I can't speak to node.js but, yes, it is possible for multiple processes to append to the same file concurrently. In a language like C or Go you would open the file with the `O_APPEND` flag. MacOS is like any other UNIX like OS in that regard (that includes Linux).